# Subparser attribute

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am having trouble composing grammars. Suppose I have a class `Derived` which inherits from `Base`. `GrammarDerived` has a `Derived` synthesized attribute while `GrammarBase` has a `Base` synthesized attribute. How can I use `GrammarBase` in a `GrammarDerived` parsing rule? I feel this should be possible because I can bind a `Base &` to a `Derived &` but nothing seems to work.

In other words, how do I get `grammarBase` to interact with `_val` by reference below?

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct GrammarDerived : public grammar <Iterator, Derived()> {
    GrammarDerived() : GrammarDerived::base_type(start) {
        start = rule1[bind(someFunc, _val)] >> grammarBase;
        rule1 = /* ... */;
    }
    rule<Iterator, Derived()> start;
    rule<Iterator, Derived()> rule1;
    GrammarBase grammarBase;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simpler setting, this shows how it's mostly a limitation of type deduction here:

```
Derived parse_result;
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, base_, qi::space, data);
```

will not work when the parser exposes a Base, however you can fix it with a "type hint" for the template instantion<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, base_, qi::space, static_cast<Base&>(data));
```

Full demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03aea89ca0df0b32)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

struct Base {
    int x;
    double y;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Base, (int,x)(double,y))

struct Derived : Base { };

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    qi::rule<It, Base(), qi::space_type> base_ = qi::int_ >> qi::double_;

    std::string const input = "1 3.14";
    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    Derived parse_result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, base_, qi::space, static_cast<Base&>(parse_result));
    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << parse_result.x << " " << parse_result.y << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
    {
        std::cout << "Input remaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

### Alternatively

You can avoid the confusion by explicitly passing a reference to the exposable attribute to the base parser/rule:

```
template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct derived_grammar : qi::grammar<It, Derived(), Skipper>
{
    derived_grammar() : derived_grammar::base_type(start) {
        base_ = qi::int_ >> qi::double_;
        glue_ = base_ [ qi::_r1 = qi::_1 ];
        start = "derived:" >> glue_(qi::_val); // passing the exposed attribute for the `Base&` reference
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, Derived(),   Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<It, void(Base&), Skipper> glue_;
    qi::rule<It, Base(),      Skipper> base_; // could be a grammar instead of a rule
};
```

If you really insist, you can do without the `glue_`/`base_` separationby using `qi::attr_cast<Base, Base>` (but I wouldn't do this for legibility).

Full code again for reference **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/078860759dfacd10)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

struct Base {
    int x;
    double y;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Base, (int,x)(double,y))

struct Derived : Base { };

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct derived_grammar : qi::grammar<It, Derived(), Skipper>
{
    derived_grammar() : derived_grammar::base_type(start) {
        base_ = qi::int_ >> qi::double_;
        glue_ = base_ [ qi::_r1 = qi::_1 ];
        start = "derived:" >> glue_(qi::_val); // passing the exposed attribute for the `Base&` reference
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, Derived(),   Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<It, void(Base&), Skipper> glue_;
    qi::rule<It, Base(),      Skipper> base_; // could be a grammar instead of a rule
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    derived_grammar<It> g;

    std::string const input = "derived:1 3.14";
    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    Derived parse_result;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, g, qi::space, parse_result);
    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << parse_result.x << " " << parse_result.y << "\n";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f != l)
    {
        std::cout << "Input remaining: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> referring to the *instantiation* of *function template* `qi::phrase_parse` here

Comment: Thanks, sehe, the glue class works nicely. Still, just for my own understanding, can you explain how I would use the first alternative (the one with the `static_cast`) in my own setting rather than the immediate `phrase_pase` thank.